# Removing HTML and XML from text

Tags: java, string

I have a series of text entries which I am trying to clear of HTML and XML. I am using the Java Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils and in general they handle things well enough if used on String s as:

```
s = unescapeHtml(s);
s = unescapeXml(s);
```

But if I have something like this:

```
    This is text. So is this. <img alt="" height="0" width="0" border="0"style="display:none"
src="http://segment-pixel.invitemedia.com/pixel?code=TechBiz
    &partnerID=167&key=segment"/><img alt="" height="0" width="0" border="0" style="display:none" src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-8bUhLiluj0fAw.gif?labels=pub.28834.rss.TechBiz
    .7020,cat.TechBiz.rss"/>
```

The Apache utils have no effect.

Can anyone suggest an alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [`Jsoup`](http://jsoup.org/):

```
String text = Jsoup.parse(html).text();
```

Which will strip off all HTML.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Java Swing also has a javax.swing.text.html.parser.*; which works.